# Toshiba Satellite a300 with Maverick keeps crashing

Tags: 10.10

I just installed 10.10 on my girlfriends Toshiba Satellite a300 and for about two days it has been working just fine for two days but today it started acting pretty wonky.

Several times over the machine just dies as if it didn't have a battery and someone yanked out the power supply. After such a crash I'll have to wait a while before powering it up again or it will die before it even reaches the startup screen.

It sort of seems like it's reacting to something I do. I kept it on for several hours while we were out of the house and it was still fine when I came back. I haven't been doing anything I can imagine is especially CPU-intensive when the crashes occur, but I have been trying to set up her iPod with Rythmbox and / or Banshee.

If anyone can point me in the right direction I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does it give the same behaviour when you boot it from - a live CD? - a live CD with another distribution? -if you installed it as a dual boot enviornment, booted in Windows? It sounds very much to me as a harware problem. The heavy CPU issues makes me think it might be an overheating-related issue? Possibly fan controllers not working properly? The `sensors` command might give some indication of problems here.

Comment: Since posting here I haven't been able to reproduce the problem. I'm crossing my fingers that it'll stay that way. Thanks a lot for your input.

Comment: Seems this was indeed a hardware issue.